# Control on accessing record - Blazor

Tags: authorization, blazor

What is the best way to ensure that a user can access a specific record? I have a page that displays account details. The URL of that account page has an ID in it for that specific account. Some users can see accounts that belong to their area, but not other areas. What's the best way to control which account details a user can access if they put an ID of an account not in their area into the URL?

Comment: check this docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: What flavor of Blazor do you use ? How do you authenticate your users ? Do you have some code that you've tried

Comment: I have been following the examples in the URL above, but I'm getting stuck in that I need to base the authorization on the record we're accessing. The AuthorizationHandler seems to get called repeatedly, so I don't want to put the DB check in there. We are using Server side Blazor. Basically i want to determine from the "areas" that a user has access to (which is retrieved using IdentityServer), and I've set up as a Claim for the user, if they satisfy a Policy of being in the same Area as the specific record we're trying to access is.

Comment: I have added the "AuthorizeView" and "Authorized" and "NotAuthorized" tags, and that seems to work ok. And when I put breakpoints into my Handler, it works (only manipulating the flow currently in debugger) - but the breakpoint is hit over and over again. I don't understand why it's hit so often, and this would be an issue with DB access.